# Why the Qlabel setText does not apply here?

Tags: python, qt

I would like to know Why the Qlabel setText does not apply here?
while I receive the variable as parameter of the function correctly.
Moreover, if I retrieve the content of the Qlabel just after doing: `self.display.label1.setText(key)` the content corresponds to my "key" variable.

I have the impression that when calling the slot, we go back to the default constructor, hence the problem

Thanks you

```
class Calculator(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self.setMinimumHeight(600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculatrice RICCO")

        self.keyboard = CalculatorKeyboard()
        self.display = CalculatorDisplay('')

        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.display.label1)
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.keyboard)
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.keyboard.Get_Grid_widget())

        self.setLayout(self.mainlayout)



    def buttonClicked(self, key):
        self.display.label1.setText(key) HERE


class CalculatorKey(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.__text = text
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: Calculator.buttonClicked(Calculator(), self.__text))


class CalculatorDisplay(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
        self.label1 = QLabel(text)
        self.label1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30))
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid gray; max-height : 50px;")


class CalculatorKeyboard(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__gridWidget = QWidget()
        self.__grid_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('C'), 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('CE'), 0, 2, 1, 2)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('7'), 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('8'), 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('9'), 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('/'), 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('4'), 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('5'), 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('6'), 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('*'), 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('1'), 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('2'), 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('3'), 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('-'), 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('0'), 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('.'), 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('='), 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.__grid_layout.addWidget(CalculatorKey('+'), 4, 3, 1, 1)

        self.__gridWidget.setLayout(self.__grid_layout)

    def Get_Grid_widget(self):
        return self.__gridWidget
```

Comment: What is this `lambda: Calculator.buttonClicked(Calculator(), self.__text)` supposed to do? You are creating a new Calculator instance, which is a widget, but you do not display it nor put it anywhere into any layout... It does not make any sense.

Comment: I would like that when you click on my button it triggers the buttonClicked(self, key):